# OAuth2 in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, oauth-2.0, dotnetopenauth

What do you think about this approach?
1. A single server for OAuth authentication and resource server, based on dotnetopenauth. 
2. Silverlight and javasrcipt interaction to access the OAuth Authorization endpoint.
e.g
Login button in silverlight page calls a javascript function to access the Authorization endpoint in server using implicit grant.
Server redirects to login page. 
User selects open id provider, login, and approve application request to access user's openid.
User access the OAuth Authorization endpoint.
Server redirect user to silverlight page again with access token in url fragment.
javascript parses the url fragment to get the access token
when silverlight page is loaded, silverlight app calls javascript function to get the accesstoken.
Silverlight uses the access token to access the resources.

Answer (score 0):

Seems reasonable to me. :)

DotNetOpenAuth won't run in Silverlight, but OAuth2 clients are very simple anyway, so I don't think that should hold you back.